# Como criar snippets para o __construct?

Tags: sublime-text

Uso o CodeIntel para PHP, mas quando tento criar o `__construct` tenho que fazer tudo manual. Alguém sabe como desenvolver o *snippet* para criar o mesmo ou tem um *plugin* próprio?

Answer (score 0):

Vá em `Tools > New Snippet`.

Em seguida, cole esse código de exemplo:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
public function __construct(${1:\$argument})
{
}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>__con</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

Salve-o na pasta `Packages/User` com o nome desejado, dando-lhe a extensão `sublime-snippet`.

Agora basta abrir um arquivo PHP e digitar `__con` para aparecer a opção do nosso pequeno `snippet` de teste.

**Observação**: Se você quiser mudar o gatilho para o `snippet` para outro nome, basta alterar o valor de `tabTrigger` para o valor desejado.